# Transfer the Pop-up message to the specific location

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can Anyone solve this problem?[pop-up message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS0cn.png)

I have this code below

```
<body>  
     <div class="contact-form-wrap responsive">

          <!--- pop-up message start --->
                <div class="status alert alert-success contact-status"></div>   
          <!--- pop-up message end --->

                    <form id="main-contact-form4" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="app.php" role="form">  

                    <legend style="padding-bottom: 20px; color: #708090;">Please provide us your information.</legend>

                            <!-- Name Filed Starts -->
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                             <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Full Name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <!-- Name Filed Ends -->

            <!---------------- Pop-up Message here ---------------->

                            <!-- Button starts -->
                                <div class="col-sm-12"> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <!-- Button Ends -->
                   </form>
                </div>
             </div>
          </body>
```

I like to move my pop-up message on the top of the button. so every time the button will press the pop-up message will notice immediately.

here is my js

```
 $(".contact-form").submit(function() {
    var rd = this;
    var url = "app.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(".contact-form").serialize(), 
        success: function(data) {
            $(rd).prev().text(data.message).fadeIn();
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Solve what problem? Just move it and test? We have no idea what your CSS looks like or how that pop up works.

Comment: I tried to move the div pop-up code on the top of the button but my pop-up message was no working

Comment: You need to let us know what you've tried, explain what happened and show us _all_ relevant code (css/js). We can't even start to help you if we don't know what your code looks like or what your actual issue is. _"Not working"_ can mean anything.

Comment: please see the updated post

Comment: Change `$(rd).prev().text(data.message).fadeIn();` to use a proper selector. Try something like: `$('.contact-status').text(data.message).fadeIn();`. It's a bad idea to select elements from their location in the DOM since you sometimes (like now) want to move them.

Comment: actually, my code is perfectly working fine, even the pop-up message. I just like to move the location of my pop^up message. but I tried so many possible answers but it won't work. please check the picture provided

Comment: oh, it works ^__^ thank you so much. how could I vote your answer?

Comment: I've posted an answer that you can accept (and upvote if you feel like it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're selecting the popup message based on it's location in the DOM. You need to select it on a proper selector instead. Since it has a class called `contact-status`, let's use that.

Change:

```
$(rd).prev().text(data.message).fadeIn();
```

to

```
$('.contact-status').text(data.message).fadeIn();
```

It's a bad idea to select elements from their location in the DOM since you sometimes (like now) want to move them. Using proper selectors (like id's or classes) will keep your code working regardless where in the DOM the element is.